# Can not run 'varnishadm' inside docker container started with varnishd

Tags: docker, docker-compose, varnish

I am running docker (via docker-compose) and can't run varnishadm from within the container. The error produced is:

```
Cannot open /var/lib/varnish/4f0dab1efca3/_.vsm: No such file or directory
Could not open shared memory
```

I have tried searching on the 'shared memory' issue and _.vsm with no luck. It seems that the _.vsm is not created at all and /var/lib/varnish/ inside the container is empty.

I have tried a variety of -T settings without any luck.

### Why run varnishadm?

The root of why I need to run varnishadm is to reload varnish while saving the cache. My backup backup backup option is to set up varnish as a service. We are on an old version of Varnish for the time being.

### How am I starting docker?

```
CMD varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/varnish.vcl \
-s malloc,1G \
-a :80
```

### Full Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get upgrade -y \
  && apt-get install wget dtrx varnish -y \
  && apt-get install pkg-config autoconf autoconf-archive automake libtool python-docutils libpcre3 libpcre3-dev xsltproc make -y \                                                    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
RUN wget https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/archive/varnish-
3.0.2.tar.gz --no-check-certificate \
  && dtrx -n varnish-3.0.2.tar.gz
WORKDIR /varnish-3.0.2/varnish-cache-varnish-3.0.2/
RUN cd /varnish-3.0.2/varnish-cache-varnish-3.0.2/ && ./autogen.sh && 
cd /varnish-3.0.2/varnish-cache-varnish-3.0.2/ && ./configure && make install

RUN cd / && wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/Dridi/libvmod-querystring/archive/v0.3.tar.gz && dtrx -n ./v0.3.tar.gz
WORKDIR /v0.3/libvmod-querystring-0.3
RUN ./autogen.sh && ./configure VARNISHSRC=/varnish-3.0.2/varnish-cache-varnish-3.0.2/ && make install

RUN cp /usr/local/lib/varnish/vmods/* /usr/lib/varnish/vmods/

WORKDIR /etc/varnish/
CMD varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/varnish.vcl \
  -s malloc,1G \
  -a :80

EXPOSE 80
```

### Full docker-compose

```
version: "3"

services:
  varnish:
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "8000:80"                                                                                                                                                                        
 volumes:
      - ./default.vcl:/etc/varnish/varnish.vcl
      - ./devicedetect.vcl:/etc/varnish/devicedetect.vcl
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: How are you running `varnishadm`? Via `docker exec` or `docker-compose exec`?

Comment: Docker-compose varnish exec ...